# Using large-scale maps/plans in Esri Story Maps

Tags: arcgis-online, scale, zoom, story-map

If there´s a possibility to adjust the scale of the basemap to plan-like maps. 
Thing is, that i´ve got a map/plan of a greenhouse and i want to make a "guide" through this greenhouse to show some rare species of plants. But there is a restriction in Story Maps builder and i can´t zoom closer to the greenhouse, so it´s so small.

You can take a look at [FLORA | Subtropický skleník](http://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapTour/index.html?appid=427b9b3cdce249d8889b324357b27df9) which is the story map.

Answer (score 3):

This is a restriction to the available levels of details in the basemap layer. You can create your own basemap with the levels that go to the scale you need.